# Match part of a string in a dataframe and replace it by entry of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm fairly new to R and I'm running into the following problem.
Let's say I have the following data frames:

```
sale_df <- data.frame("Cheese" = c("cheese-01", "cheese-02", "cheese-03"), "Number_of_sales" = c(4, 8, 23))
id_df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 2, 3), "Name" = c("Leerdammer", "Gouda", "Mozerella")
```

What I want to do is match the numbers of the first column of `id_df` to the numbers in the string of the first column of `sale_df`.

Then I want to replace the value in `sale_df` by the value in the second column of `id_df`, i.e. I want `cheese-01` to become `"Leerdammer"`.

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

With tidyverse :

```
sale_df %>% mutate(ID=as.numeric(str_extract(Cheese,"(?<=cheese-).*"))) %>% inner_join(id_df,by="ID")

#     Cheese Number_of_sales ID       Name
#1 cheese-01               4  1 Leerdammer
#2 cheese-02               8  2      Gouda
#3 cheese-03              23  3  Mozerella
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all entries for `Cheese` in `sale_df` will start with cheese-, here is a simple solution.

```
sale_df$CheeseID <- as.numeric(substring(sale_df$Cheese, 8))
merge(sale_df, id_df, by.x = "CheeseID", by.y = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 sale_df$Number_of_sales=id_df$Name[match(id_df$ID,as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",sale_df$Cheese)))]
> sale_df
     Cheese Number_of_sales
1 cheese-01      Leerdammer
2 cheese-02           Gouda
3 cheese-03       Mozerella
```

Comment: The result column should be `Name`, not `Number_of_sales`. And, please, explain your code a little bit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas is that the reason you downvoted? downvoting occurs in the case a solution given is completely wrong. here you could have obtained the idea and changed the column name. downvoting will make people not to answer your questions. it is better not to vote rather than downvote

Comment: Not my downvote. I wrote that because it came up in the review queue.